# When compressing a large amount of files, 7zip stops while only returning "Killed"

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, 7-zip

Recently a computer of mine died and I'm trying to recover the files (650GB approximately) using a live ubuntu usb to compress the files and then move them to an external HDD. I don't just want to move them because the space on the HDDs I have currently is limited.

I input the command:

`7za a downloads.7z *`
in the downloads folder, expecting it to compress everything in there, but at a specific file (always the same one) it stops, only adding "Killed" to the end of the filename, like so:

`0% 14 + books/impracticalpythonprojects.pdfKilled`

I'm guessing it could be due to two reasons: a character in the filename which 7zip isn't dealing with correctly or the file is using too much memory and some other process is killing it, which was hinted to in a solution I saw elsewhere, but they didn't elaborate on how to do it and I can't find anything on google.

Comment: Could be a corrupt file, more likely.  Do you dare to run a drive fix utility?

Comment: I tried retrieving a couple of the files it stops on separately and they seem to work fine, so I doubt it's that.

Comment: [Possibility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153586/108618)?

Comment: Then I think @KamilMaciorowski is on target here :)

Comment: Have you tried running 'top' while this command is running, and watching its memory use?  That should give you a hint as to whether that is at issue (if it approaches the available RAM on the system, for example).

Comment: you don't mention a suspected cause of original system death, but it begs the question, have you checked the drives S.M.A.R.T. Report?  smartctl -a /dev/___

Comment: The system died due to an unexpected problem updating to ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04. For some reason it runs so slow I can barely type. I doubt it's a hard-drive issue.

As far as OOM, I tried doing what the answer of this (https://serverfault.com/questions/141988/avoid-linux-out-of-memory-application-teardown) question mentions and ended up with the following error at every command including shutdown: "bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a memory issue, since after checking top there's only .09GB out of 1.9GB of memory available. I'm sure the live cd is taking up most of that. I'll try switching to a server live image, but if that doesn't work, is there a workaround?